# mysql show unical groups and sum quantities inside groups

Tags: php, mysql, sum, distinct

MySql
I have some unical groups with 10+ lines with 2 same strings (date and ref)
Mysql database:

```
id  name    qty     ref     weight  date
1   name1   2       x1      22      2011-01-01
2   name2   3       x1      13      2011-01-01
3   name3   4       x2      10      2021-02-02
4   name4   5       x2      15      2021-02-02
```

Could you please help, how I can get only unical results  and summ qty and weight of the groups, like that:

```
ref weight  qty date
x1  35      5   2011-01-01
x2  25      9   2021-02-02
```

I tryed distinct, but in this case cant get sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use [The SQL GROUP BY Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) :

```
SELECT ref, sum(weight) as weight,sum(qty) as qty, date  
FROM tablename GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
SELECT sum(weight),sum(qty) from tablename GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT ref, sim(weight) as weight, sum(qty) as qty, date
FROM table_name
GROUP BY CONCAT(ref, date)
```